# Detect a DLL file-name with a particular prefix using regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am trying to get use a regex pattern to detect if a dll file-name:

- Starts with `module_`
- Ends with `.dll`
- And all the characters in between are **non special** alphanumeric characters

Here is the code I'm using:

```
bool IsModule(std::string const& name)
{
    static std::regex const regex("^module_[:alnum:]+\\.dll");
    return std::regex_match(name, regex);
}
```

Using an online regex debugger, I couldn't figure the issue out.  When I test it using `module_custom.dll` as the input file-name, it does not see it as a match.

**[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63120f9d73c1978e)**

Comment: Side note, you probably want to end your regex with a `$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[:alnum:]` character class does not appear to be supported by C++ 11 regex engine.  According to [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), it is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, so you could just do this:

```
bool IsModule(std::string const& name)
{
    static std::regex const regex("^module_[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.dll$");
    return std::regex_match(name, regex);
}
```

Note that I added the `$` anchor at the end, as Mike mentioned in the comments above.  If you omit that, it will consider something like `module_custom.dllfoo` to be a valid match.

The `[:alnum:]` character class is a peculiarity of the POSIX regex flavor.  I'm not familiar with regex in C++, but [it appears](http://www.regular-expressions.info/stdregex.html) that the default engine is compatible with EMACScript rather than POSIX. According to [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type), however, it looks like it may be possible to switch it to use a POSIX compatable engine?  If using POSIX regex syntax is important to you, perhaps someone more knowledgeable could jump in with more information about that.

Comment: If you want underscore to be allowed you need to add this as well

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
bool IsModule(std::string const& name)
{
    static std::regex const regex("^module_\\w+\\.dll");
    return std::regex_match(name, regex);
}
```

Not sure if :alphanum: works with C++ 11.

Comment: Could you list special characters?

Comment: Or what exactly is allowed?